# Facebook php, how to filter out the feeds

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm getting facebooks page feeds: `$fb->api('/415533455147213/feed?limit=3');`, and my question: how to filter this request that it doesn't return feeds which has a type named `status` (`'type' => 'status')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an FQL query such as

```
$fb->api( array(
                     'method' => 'fql.query',
                     'query' => 'SELECT message from stream where source_id =415533455147213 and type != 46',
                 ));
  //you might need to urlencode the query
```

You can find information on the fields to pull back here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: omg, tried this way but with `type <> 46`... Thanks, works now ;]]